# Does package management of a WinPython installation depend on the machine?

Tags: python, pip, python-install

I have a WinPython installation on a network server that I can access from two different machines. As the installation is portable, I would expect the packages versions to be the same whether I use one or the other machine.

However, I recently downgraded tensorflow from 2.9 to 2.6 using machine A, and when I check the installed version, I get:

- 2.6 when running the command from machine A.
- 2.9 when running the command from machine B.

What should I do on machine B to fix the situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the issue. When downgrading tensorflow I used the --user option, so 2.6 version was installed in a user-specific location of machine A, not accessible from machine B.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).